# whisper on private network. subscribe error

Tags: whisper

I'm use [THIS GUIDE](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Whisper-Usage) for start Testing the Whisper node (geth) on private network. 
Version Geth: /v1.6.7-stable-ab5646c5. Version Whisper: 5.

Start with this command :`geth --shh --testnet --nodiscover console`. 
 Connect to the test node: `admin.addPeer("enode://d25474361659861e9e651bc728a17e807a3359ca0d344afd544ed0f11a31faecaf4d74b55db53c6670fd624f08d5c79adfc8da5dd4a11b9213db49a3b750845e@52.178.209.125:30379")`
In answer get `true`
 Try Case [Receive Asymmetrically Encrypted Messages](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Whisper-Usage#receive-asymmetrically-encrypted-messages) 
Generate a key pair, and save its ID.
`> id = shh.newKeyPair()
"f87747702c8d4dc9b9abf889e77ca9bf36d9f87b23fcc3ed09ff1976e52ce4d3"`
Retrieve and save public key.
`> shh.getPublicKey("f87747702c8d4dc9b9abf889e77ca9bf36d9f87b23fcc3ed09ff1976e52ce4d3")
"0x04ea9a8e0fc1d831e4dc094e2769989a82f3094ff774e133ec733cf9940b7c73792ab634883ef1cdf17be2f6081571dbac98c2c73e3362420e6ab53c7687a82079"`
And try subscribe to messages,  encrypted with certain public key.
`> f = shh.subscribe({type: 'asym', key: id})
Error: Invalid number of input parameters 
    at web3.js:3094:20
    at web3.js:4931:15
    at web3.js:4974:5
    at web3.js:4998:23
    at <anonymous>:1:5`
Parameters for Subscribe:
`type       string
 key        string
 sig        string
 minPoW     float64
 topics     [][]byte
 allowP2P   bool`
Create Public Key for `sig`:
`> var pubk = shh.getPublicKey(id)`
And try this command:
`> f = shh.subscribe({type: 'asym', key: id, sig: pubk, minPoW: 1, topics: ['0x07678231'], allowP2P: true})
Error: Invalid number of input parameters
    at web3.js:3094:20
    at web3.js:4931:15
    at web3.js:4974:5
    at web3.js:4998:23
    at <anonymous>:1:5`
But I get the same error. Internet search on this error did not yield results. How to fix this behavior?